# Как запретить наследование класса в C#

Tags: c#

Как запретить наследование класса в C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для предотвращения наследования от класса необходимо объявить его с модификатором sealed. Например, если мы не хотим чтобы от класса SomeClass можно было наследоваться, то объявляем его так:

```
sealed class SomeClass
{
    // Объявление класса
}
```

Answer (score 6):

В качестве альтернативы, можно запретить и создание экземпляров этого класса с помощью ключевого слова `static` (под капотом, будет использована пара модификаторов: `abstract sealed`).

```
static class Helper
{
  // допустимы лишь статические методы
}
```